# CSS DIV prices are not aligned if I get a long description

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

Prices are not aligned if I get a long description. See here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXgaj.jpg

JSFiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/2n19tv75/

```css
.border-gray {
  border: 1px solid #e5e7eb;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 185px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-item-name {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu-item-price {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu-item-desc {
  float: left;
  color: #889194;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.menu-item-image {
  float: right;
}

.menu-sectionname {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu-row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 2rem !important;
  /* control column gap */
  --bs-gutter-y: 2rem !important;
  /* control row gap */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
      <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuSection">
        <div class="menu-sectionname">
          <h4>h4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-section row menu-row">
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-image">
                <img itemprop="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZIsnpPF.jpg?auto=format&amp;w=120&amp;h=120" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p>working good</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€5.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-image">
                <img itemprop="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZIsnpPF.jpg?auto=format&amp;w=120&amp;h=120" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p>working good</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€4.50</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-sectionname">
          <h4>h4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-section row menu-row">
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> desc 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€8.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€10.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> desc 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€10.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus,
                  quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus
                  fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€10.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can use a fixed height on your description div and then overflow hidden or scroll

Comment: if I use max-height; and overflow-y: hidden; half of the text will disappear, also I can't have a scroll bar there too, understand? just the prices have to be aligned all the time does not matter the size of the description of the text.

Comment: I don't understand here that align with what? Because i see in the picture that the last two where you have green arrows that indicates height mismatch between two description div.

Comment: This happened because there is lot of content without any fixed height so the contents are automatically gets height to fit content length. You should reduce text content or add read more button or increase the div height

Comment: Add height not max-height

Comment: You really shouldn't be using floats in modern layout. Use the techniques that your layout library uses--inline-block and flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [`align-items-baseline`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) class to each row start.

```css
.border-gray {
  border: 1px solid #e5e7eb;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 185px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-item-name {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu-item-price {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu-item-desc {
  float: left;
  color: #889194;
  width: 60%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: inline-block;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.menu-item-image {
  float: right;
}

.menu-sectionname {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.menu-row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 2rem !important;
  /* control column gap */
  --bs-gutter-y: 2rem !important;
  /* control row gap */
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
      <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/MenuSection">
        <div class="menu-sectionname">
          <h4>h4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-section row align-items-baseline menu-row">
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-image">
                <img itemprop="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZIsnpPF.jpg?auto=format&amp;w=120&amp;h=120" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p>working good</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€5.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-image">
                <img itemprop="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/ZIsnpPF.jpg?auto=format&amp;w=120&amp;h=120" alt="" />
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p>working good</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€4.50</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-sectionname">
          <h4>h4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-section row align-items-baseline menu-row">
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> desc 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€8.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€10.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> desc 3</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€10.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="menu-item col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 border-gray-no-image">
            <div class="border-gray">
              <div class="menu-item-name">
                <p>p text</p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-desc">
                <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                  consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus,
                  quis lobortis augue. Vivamus fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non vehicula tellus, quis lobortis augue. Vivamus
                  fermentum maximus sapien sit amet semper. Vivamus in nunc id magna consectetur laoreet. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="menu-item-price">
                <span itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/offers"><span itemprop="price"><p>€10.00</p></span></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks but now the gray boxes are in different sizes if I open in a bigger resolution

Comment: @raduken that is because of your floats... can I remove them?

Comment: Yes of course you can remove, i use float to try align my divs

Comment: @raduken my answer on your new question help out?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the text to disappear, you could just make the text box with a set height that's large enough to hold the longest text but I don't think that's what you want.

If the price being aligned is that important, you could change the location to the side of the text using flexbox or above the text so it doesn't matter how long the text is.